# is not a valid value for a primary key - ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When i try to save ModelForm with **models.ManyToManyField** it throws an error 'Value  is not a valid value for a primary key'.
Also the initial values that I set in '**def __init__**' only works in admin panel, but not in frontend.

And how do i configure it to show only if no data in database, but if data is in it will shows initial in form (to edit)? By the wa there is no little '+' near the field, so how user will add values?

forms.py:

```
class UserprojectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Userproject
        fields = ['name', 'user', 'description', 'vk_groups', 'source_name', 'date_updated', 'date_until'] #'date_created',  cannot add django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (date_created) specified for Userproject
        # widgets = {
        #     'vk_groups': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}),
        #     'source_name': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 5}),
        # }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserprojectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #vk_groups = [(v.id,v.buid) for v in Userproject.objects.exclude(buid='').order_by('buid')]
        vk_groups = (('https://vk.com/southitpark','https://vk.com/southitpark'), ('https://vk.com/graphgrail', 'https://vk.com/graphgrail'))
        source_names = (('Вконтакте', 'Вконтакте'), ('Facebook', 'Facebook'), ('Twitter (скоро)', 'Twitter (скоро)'))
        self.fields['vk_groups'].choices = vk_groups
        self.fields['source_name'].choices = source_names
```

models.py:

```
    class Userproject(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = u'Проект мониторинга'
            verbose_name_plural = u'Проекты мониторинга'


        vk_groups = models.ManyToManyField(Vkgroupstomonitor, null=True, blank=True, related_name="vkgroups", verbose_name=_("Группы Вконтакте"))
        source_name = models.ManyToManyField(Sourcetomonitor, null=True, blank=True, related_name="sourcename", verbose_name=_("Название источника"))

        name = models.CharField(u'Название проекта', unique=True, max_length=255)
.......
```

views.py:

```
class UserprojectCreate(CreateView):
model = Userproject
template_name = 'userproject_form.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('userproject_list')
fields = ['name', 'description', 'vk_groups', 'source_name', 'date_updated'] 

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(UserprojectCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: @Sayse edited code to clean up

Comment: You're asking too many questions at once. Focus on one of the problems that you have, so it's easier for others that are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to specify **queryset** instead of **choices**. The latter does not seem to be a part of design of [this field class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) at all.

BTW, in my opinion, it would be better to include this into explicit declaration of the form`s fields rather than patch them in **init** method.